# Jboss5 struts1 ajax response data limited

Tags: json, ajax, struts-1, jboss5.x

I'm working in a system that's doing an ajax request (HTTP GET) to a struts action and is waiting for a JSON response, when the json string is small there's no problem, however when the string have more then 8k characters the json is being cut.

I've tried to increase maxHttpHeaderSize from jboss 5 but the behavior of cutting the json continue. So what do I need to configure to increase this limit of 8kb?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You're sending the JSON data in a header?

Comment: I was sending in a request attribute, I've changes to the response outputstream and it worked.